# On Travis CI, At what point does "cleanup" occur?

Tags: travis-ci

At what point in the build process does the deployment cleanup occur? Is it part of the `deploy` step, or `before_deploy`?

In other words, if I want to create a tarball to deploy to Github/S3, can I assume cleanup has occurred by the time Travis will run a `tar` command I will put in a `before_deploy` step? Or will cleanup not happen until after my `before_deploy` steps have run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears cleanup occurs during `deploy`:

```
store build cache 12.69s
change detected:

/home/travis/build/zsturgess/overwatch/vendor/autoload.php

/home/travis/build/zsturgess/overwatch/vendor/autoload.php

/home/travis/build/zsturgess/overwatch/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php

/home/travis/build/zsturgess/overwatch/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php

changes detected, packing new archive

.

uploading archive
before_deploy.1 0.91s

$ composer install --no-dev --no-scripts --prefer-dist

Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "/home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6/bin/composer self-update" to get the latest version.

Loading composer repositories with package information

Installing dependencies from lock file

  - Removing scrutinizer/ocular (1.1.1)

  - Removing guzzle/guzzle (v3.9.3)

  - Removing jms/serializer (0.16.0)

  - Removing phpcollection/phpcollection (0.4.0)

  - Removing jms/parser-lib (1.0.0)

  - Removing phpoption/phpoption (1.5.0)

  - Removing jms/metadata (1.5.1)

  - Removing phpunit/phpunit (4.8.7)

  - Removing phpunit/php-code-coverage (2.2.3)

  - Removing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.4.8)

  - Removing php-mock/php-mock-phpunit (0.3)

  - Removing php-mock/php-mock-integration (0.4)

  - Removing php-mock/php-mock (0.8)

  - Removing facebook/webdriver (1.0.2)

  - Removing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (2.3.7)

  - Removing sensio/generator-bundle (v2.5.3)

  - Removing phpspec/prophecy (v1.5.0)

  - Removing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.1)

  - Removing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.7)

  - Removing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1)

  - Removing sebastian/comparator (1.2.0)

  - Removing sebastian/diff (1.3.0)

  - Removing sebastian/environment (1.3.2)

  - Removing sebastian/exporter (1.2.1)

  - Removing sebastian/recursion-context (1.0.1)

  - Removing sebastian/version (1.0.6)

  - Removing liip/functional-test-bundle (1.2.2)

  - Removing doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle (v2.2.1)

  - Removing doctrine/data-fixtures (v1.1.1)

  - Removing sebastian/global-state (1.0.0)

  - Removing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (2.0.4)

Generating autoload files
before_deploy.2 0.00s
$ cp app/config/parameters.yml.dist app/config/parameters.yml
before_deploy.3 5.77s
$ tar -czf overwatch-$TRAVIS_TAG.tar.gz app/ composer* *.md LICENSE src/ vendor/ web/
dpl.0

Fetching: dpl-1.8.2.gem (100%)

Successfully installed dpl-1.8.2

1 gem installed

18.49s
dpl.1

Installing deploy dependencies

Fetching: addressable-2.3.8.gem (100%)

Successfully installed addressable-2.3.8

Fetching: multipart-post-2.0.0.gem (100%)

Successfully installed multipart-post-2.0.0

Fetching: faraday-0.9.1.gem (100%)

Successfully installed faraday-0.9.1

Fetching: sawyer-0.6.0.gem (100%)

Successfully installed sawyer-0.6.0

Fetching: octokit-4.1.0.gem (100%)

Successfully installed octokit-4.1.0

5 gems installed

Fetching: mime-types-2.6.2.gem (100%)

Successfully installed mime-types-2.6.2

1 gem installed

dpl.2

Preparing deploy

Logged in as Zac Sturgess

Deploying to repo: zsturgess/overwatch

Current tag is: v0.0.1-alpha.5

Ignoring path vendor/doctrine/annotations/

Ignoring path vendor/doctrine/cache/

Ignoring path vendor/doctrine/collections/

Ignoring path vendor/doctrine/common/

Ignoring path vendor/doctrine/inflector/

Ignoring path vendor/doctrine/lexer/

Ignoring path vendor/psr/log/

Ignoring path vendor/symfony/symfony/

Ignoring path vendor/twig/twig/

/usr/lib/git-core/git-stash: 186: /usr/lib/git-core/git-stash: cannot create /home/travis/build/zsturgess/overwatch/.git/logs/refs/stash: Directory nonexistent
```

You can see that Travis CI attempts to run a `git stash` after the various commands I'd put in `before_deploy`